# php - how to get the return from mysqldump when I use exec()?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use mysqldump from my php script using exec() function.

I did that in php

```
$com = "mysqldump --user=username --password=mypassword mydatabasename >c:\dump\test.sql";
$exec($com,$result); var_dump($result);
```

It always return an empty test.sql file in the specified location , and `$result` is always an empty array.

The thing is, when I write the same exact line in the `CMD` it **works!**

I tried using shell_exec() and the result also is empty string. I also tried adding --host=localhost , but nothing happens either.

I work on Windows local machine with Xampp server, my mysqldump is MariaDB.

1. why the same line works in CMD , but not from the php script?
2. how to get the result from the exec() function to know where my error is?

Comment: user\file permission issue probaby

Comment: @Dagon Do you mean mysqldump doesn't have permission to write in the specified location?

Comment: @Dagon but it writs an empty file when I call it from the php . and when I run it -`mysqldump`-, from cmd,  it writes the complete backup file in the `same` location . so `mysqldump` writes in the folder in both cases .  is there something I mess?

Comment: its the user that doe the call that matters, in one case its what ever php is running as in the other what ever your logged in as

Comment: @Dagon thank you sir for your time  and help , I got it , when I add `2>` to mysqldump it outputs the errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/249853/does-mysqldump-return-a-status

that answer made me almost cry.
I finally goooooooot itttttt!
I added `2>c:/dump/database.err` to the call, and boooooooooooooooooom it did output the error finally.

> "mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

I corrected the full path name and got it done. oh man I hate programming :(